# Display total below HTML/CSS table

Tags: javascript, html, css, table-footer

I have created some tables which display transactions with the last column being the amount fields. I need to display a total/subtotal just below this column. The problem is my table columns are set to % widths.

How can I ensure that the field displaying the total amount will be below the amount columns.

I think I need some kind of CSS code to keep the total field(div/span) tied to the table width but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks.

Example:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Amount
A      B    C    100
D      E    F    100
          Total: 200
```

EDIT: I should also have said that this table is dynamic. Its created using Visualforce (a native force.com language). The UI is then rendered into HTML and I do have CSS to format the resulting HTML table. Since I have no idea in advance of how many rows I can have, I cannot simply add a row for the totals and wanted to see if there was a better solution.

Comment: are you familiar with the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes?

Comment: A total or subtotal of all of the columns in a table is still part of the tabular data, so it still belongs within the table.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**CODE**

```css
<!-- Style -->
<style>
   #total {
      text-align:right;
   }

   #table {
      border:1px solid red;
      border-collapse:separate;
   }

   #table th, #table td {
      border:1px solid #000;
   }
</style>
```

```html
<!-- Table -->
<table id="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Col1</th>
     <th>Col2</th>
     <th>Col3</th>
     <th>Amount</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>A</td>
     <td>B</td>
     <td>C</td>
     <td>100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>D</td>
     <td>E</td>
     <td>F</td>
     <td>100</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th id="total" colspan="3">Total :</th>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>
```

The 'Total' label is located in `th` that spans 2 columns (check cinnamon comment). A style applied to this cell moves all text on the right. The total number (200) is aligned with the other results.

Comment: You have the right idea with the markup, but the tfoot should contain 2 cells:  th (Total) and td (200).

Answer (score 3):

You may try this

**CSS**

```
tbody tr{text-align:center; /*If you want to center align of row text*/}
.right{text-align:right;}​
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Amount</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td class="right">100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td class="right">100</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="right" colspan="3">Total:</td><td class="right">200</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9SBu/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a table footer, then you can use the whole width.

Comment: Actually using a footer for my Visualforce table might do the trick.

Comment: You know it makes sense Richard. Heres a good example http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/organizing-data-tables

Answer (score 0):

Add the `colspan` attribute to your last `td` and align your text to the right.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td class="total-column" colspan="4">
    Total:200
    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.total-column {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `colspan` for your 'total' label:

```
<table border="1>"
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Col1</th>
        <th width="25%">Col2</th>
        <th width="25%">Col3</th>
        <th width="25%">Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:right;">total:</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Styles (width, text-align) should always be out of table structure.

Comment: @Stephan Of course; this was just a quick answer to the question.