# How to have Total and Average lines at the bottom of a tall table, keeping rows normal-sized?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

Is there a way in CSS (no JS) to have a table of a given height, but with Total and Average lines at the bottom, yet keeping rows (except perhaps a spacer row) normal-sized?

If the are too many rows to fit, there is no extra space between the Total row and the one before it, and the whole table can be scrolled.

I know I can use two tables, but the width of the cells must fit their contents and it would be difficult to get the tables to match.

[Display total below HTML/CSS table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568536/display-total-below-html-css-table) suggests using tfoot, but all the cells stretch if I increase the table height.

For example:

```
INTENDED:                  NOT INTENDED:          
--------------- ^          --------------- ^      
Creature  Value |          Creature  Value |      
--------------- |                          |      
Aardvark     10 |          --------------- |      
--------------- |          Aardvark     10 |      
Bluebird     20 |                          |      
--------------- |          --------------- |      
Chipmunk     30 |          Bluebird     20 |      
--------------- |                          |      
Dopefish     40 |table     --------------- |table 
--------------- |height    Chipmunk     30 |height
                |                          |      
                |          --------------- |      
                |          Dopefish     40 |      
                |                          |      
                |          --------------- |      
                |          Total       100 |      
--------------- |                          |      
Total       100 |          --------------- |      
--------------- |          Average      25 |      
Average      25 |                          |      
--------------- V          --------------- V
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you just add an id to the total and have a set margin-top to it?

Comment: I'd think not...at least not as an actual `table`.